# How can I access the content variable from within Extbase extension when called by postuserfunc?

Tags: typo3, extbase

As dokumented in [api.typo3.org](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_core_1_1_bootstrap.html#a890c7dde66b4a9462983759de4d9576a) the content parameter of Bootstrap->run is not used.
I need a way to process exactly this content within an extbase extension.

The extension is called by:

```
    page = PAGE
    page {
        stdWrap {
            htmlSpecialChars = 0
            postUserFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
            postUserFunc {
                extensionName = MyExtension         
                pluginName   = Pi1
                controller   = Firstcontroller
                vendorName    = MyCompany
                action       = list 


            }
        }
       ......
```

How can I access the (postuserfunc-)content? 
I tried to use the ContentObject, but couldn't find the content anywhere.

```
$this->configurationManager->getContentObject()
```

Is there a workaround?

Cheers 
Wirsing

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to get at the cObject record? You're almost there:

```
$contentRecord = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->data;
```